# I have received a TypeError (Uncaught TypeError: https.createServer is not a function) when I try to test https. Can someone helps please?

Tags: javascript, ssl, https, wss

Im a new front end developer and I was trying to set up a new HTTPS environment. I followed the instruction from  [a link](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html) under https.createServer([options][, requestlistener]) section. But somehow it gives me an error of https.createServer is not a function. Can someone please help me with the question?

I was using browserify to compile:

```
    $npm install browserify --save
    $browserify test.js -o bundle.js -t brfs
```

The following is my code (test.js):

```
    var fs = require('fs'),
    https = require('https')
    var options = {
            ca: fs.readFileSync('ca.pem', 'utf8'),
            cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem', 'utf8'),
            rejectUnauthorized: true
    };

    httpsServer = https.createServer(options, (req,res) => {
            res.writeHead(200);
            res.end('hello world\n');
    }).listen(443);
```

and the error that i was receiving:

```
    Uncaught TypeError: https.createServer is not a function
```

I have also tried many other ways includes using

```
    var express = require('express'),
        app = express()
```

and eventually it gives me another error:

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
```

Comment: It's not clear from your question if this is front end or backend. The code you're using is from Node.js meant to run on the server. Are you trying to run this in the browser?

Comment: For help asking a good question take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask For this question it would be very helpful if you could tell us how to reproduce your issue. Take a look at this helpful page https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Yes, i am trying to run this in the browser by compile the code through browserify.